# Variable in AWK command result outputs to the wrong position

Tags: awk

I'm making bash script which takes data from two columns in *.txt file and compiles command.

```
awk -F":" '{print "./otherscript.py " $1 " -s " $2 "--username user.user --password password"}' /home/el/1.txt
```

So it's supposed to get

```
./otherscript.py BLA1 -s BLA2 --username user.user --password password /home/el/1.txt
```

What I get is

```
./otherscript.py BLA1 BLA2 -s --username user.user --password password /home/el/1.txt
```

, so variable $2 seem to place itself not where it supposed to go. Any ideas what might be the reason?

Comment: You set the field separator to `:` (with `-F":"`), but your fields are separated by a space.  (If you just print `$1` you'll see it's set to `BLA1 BLA2`, and if you just print `$2` you'll see it's empty.)

Comment: OMG thank you so much! You are absolutely right!